# AJAX forces page refresh (but shouldn't)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Simple AJAX test page using JQuery.
Displayed page initially shows button (BUTTON1). On click, it will run react.php through script.js. react.php will replace BUTTON1 with BUTTON2 through span element. All this works.

Here's where it goes wrong. Click on BUTTON2 should run react2.php through script2.js. react2.php should then replace BUTTON2 with text "SUCCESS". Instead of doing this, though, when clicking on BUTTON2, the page refreshes (and displays BUTTON1 once again).

When class of button on initial beginning.php page is changed from button1 to button2, button is successfully replaced with string from react2.php. I cannot get to the bottom of this.

How do I prevent the refresh so that the page displays "SUCCESS" in the span element?
Thanks in advance!

beginning.php

```
 <html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
<?php
echo "<span class='span_display'>
    <a href='' id='button1' class='button1'>BUTTON1</a>&nbsp;
</span>";
?>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(function() {
    $(".button1").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "react.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $(".span_display").html(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

script2.js

```
...(all the same except)
   url: "react2.php",
```

react.php

```
<?php
echo "<a href='' id='button2' class='like_button2'>BUTTON2</a>&nbsp;";
?>
```

react2.php

```
<?php
echo "SUCCESS";
?>
```

Comment: Because your script doesn't recognize the button2. you have to put it in your markup (hide it, and show it after your first button click) or you have to output your button2 click handler in your react.php. would go with the first option though. i dont post it as an answer because im not 100% sure about the second option and i got no time to test it right now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am sorry, could you please expand your answer with some hints or examples on how to put this principle into code? Do you mean along the lines of this: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp) ? Beginner here.

Comment: As you seem to be a new user on SO, I'd like to encourage you to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about) or read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how (and why) to accept answers. ;-) And please, don't use w3schools as a resource but the [official documentation](api.jquery.com/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem results from the missing click handler on your second link, as it's added dynamically via ajax. It is generally advisable to use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of attaching handlers directly to elements:

```
function handler(uri) {
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $(".span_display").html(html);
        }
    });
}

$(document)
    .on("click", "#button1, #button2", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var uri = $(this).hasClass("button1") ? "react.php" : "react2.php";
        handler(uri);
    });
});
```

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) explains it magnificent, so I'll just quote it:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.
>
> In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements
>   not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their
>   potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be
>   monitored.

Comment: It took me a while to understand this code and how it should work, but I think I get the principle now. It still doesn't work, though. I put your code snippet into script.js and disabled script2.js in beginning.php. Now clicking BUTTON1 refreshes the page to display BUTTON1 again.

Comment: I got it working now. Your method did the thing. It was just that i had left a simple mistake in the script.js file when I imported your code. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Minion Great to hear. I also updated your [jsBin example](http://jsbin.com/OqohipA/5) with a working solution (please note that I had to mock the `$.ajax()` call obviously). ;-)

Comment: Oh, nice. I was wondering how I was supposed to make it work. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that button2 is created by Ajax.

The script2.js is executed on the first load of the page, before button 2 exists and therefore cannot bind any events to button2 (it does not exist).

When button 2 is created and then clicked it acts as a normal button submitting the page.

<strike>Either you have to force script 2 to run after button 2 is loaded. You could do this by calling a method from script2 in the success in script 1 after creating the button.</strike>

Or you could look on live events in jquery, they can lock on to new elements that are created.

I would go with option 1 in this case though, its cleaner and more predictable.

Use the script from nietonfir, it is easier.

Comment: Please read the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) about `on()` and delegated events in general. OPs scenario can easily be handled by one event listener (with minor logic adjustments for the target URI). `//Just to make sure the dom is finished` should be the very first hint that you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I made a note about live events which is the old name for delegate events. I still think it is a worse solution as it can make for a more complex page if you have many different events on different levels. In this case I think a direct solution is better, especially if there could be many different new buttons that should bind to different events, but that is a matter of opinion.  Is my answer wrong in any way?

Comment: The note on Dom finishing is that I have memories of the html command ,used to at least, finish before the dom was actually ready. This might be better, but for older browsers it could still be valid unless jquery makes it 100 % certain that the dom is done.

Comment: Yes, I think it is wrong because you intentionally add complexity. What would you do if a third/fourth/fifth button are added to the page? Bind more functions to the dom (after that timeout hack)? That's not very DRY nor KISS!

Comment: Both solutions work, yours is probably the better in this case, but you fail to describe the real reason WHY you have to do it that way, which I think is the most important part in answering the question.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation here, David.